# set the background for the slide hover

Tags: jquery, hover, slider, slick.js

I use a slick slider and everything works fine. There are two slides. When placing the mouse on one of the slides it is necessary to set a translucent background and add a button

my HTML

```
<div class="wrapper_middle_btn">
            </div>
            <div class="wrapper_vn">
                  <input class="middle_btn" type="button" onclick="#" value="Замовити">
            </div>
```

.

```
wrapper_middle_btn{

  display: flex;
  align-items: flex-end;
  height: 350px;
  position: absolute;
  width: 9.9%;
  bottom: 10%;
  padding-top: 20px;

  opacity: 0;
  background: #000;


}
.middle_btn {

  color: white;
  width: 100%;
  height: 50px;
  background: red;

}
 .wrapper_vn{
   opacity: 0;
  display: flex;
  align-items: flex-end;
  height: 50px;
  position: absolute;
  width: 9.9%;
  bottom: 0;
  padding-top: 20px;
}


$(function() {
  $('.wrapper_middle_btn').hover(function() {
    $('.wrapper_vn').css('opacity', '1');
    $('.wrapper_middle_btn').css('opacity', '0.5');
  }, function() {
    // on mouseout, reset the background colour
    $('.wrapper_vn').css('opacity', '0');
    $('.wrapper_middle_btn').css('opacity', '0');
  });
});
$(function() {
  $('.wrapper_vn').hover(function() {
    $('.wrapper_vn').css('opacity', '1');
    $('.wrapper_middle_btn').css('opacity', '0.5');
  }, function() {
    // on mouseout, reset the background colour
    $('.wrapper_vn').css('opacity', '0');
    $('.wrapper_middle_btn').css('opacity', '0');
  });
});
```

when hovering on one slide, the background is set for two slids.
help

Comment: make `wrapper_middle_btn:hover` opacity to 1 like this`.wrapper_middle_btn:hover{
  opacity: 1;
}`

Comment: the whole slide closes with a black square.
I need to close the image with a semi-transparent background and a button that was not transparent